# Can't understand symbolicated crash report

Tags: ios, crash, crash-reports, symbolicatecrash, symbolicate

I have downloaded symbolicated crash report using Xcode but unable to understand it as in backtrace it shows below method where it crashed:
`-[UIView(Internal) _addSubview:positioned:relativeTo:] + 132 (UIView.m:16297)`. However, I can't find that specific method in my code where exception occurred. Below is the crash report:

```
Incident Identifier: 36EACC3D-E19F-4F23-B788-CD18C8D21052
Hardware Model:      iPad13,4
Process:             SuperApp [1625]
Path:                /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/5AEC3228-FC0F-48FA-9812-276AAD48B44D/SuperApp.app/SuperApp
Identifier:          sa.com.stc.SuperMobileApp
Version:             1.0 (1.4.0)
AppStoreTools:       12E262
AppVariant:          1:iPad13,4:14
Beta:                YES
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Role:                Foreground
Parent Process:      launchd [1]
Coalition:           sa.com.stc.SuperMobileApp [793]

Date/Time:           2021-06-20 17:34:25.7885 +0300
Launch Time:         2021-06-19 22:08:42.5573 +0300
OS Version:          iPhone OS 15.0 (19A5261w)
Release Type:        Beta
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Triggered by Thread:  0

Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x18082ff90 __exceptionPreprocess + 220 (NSException.m:199)
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x198eeb21c objc_exception_throw + 60 (objc-exception.mm:565)
2   CoreFoundation                  0x1808bcce0 +[NSException raise:format:] + 112 (NSException.m:155)
3   UIKitCore                       0x182c4a458 -[UIView(Internal) _addSubview:positioned:relativeTo:] + 132 (UIView.m:16297)
4   UIKitCore                       0x182ff5638 __53-[_UINavigationParallaxTransition animateTransition:]_block_invoke_2 + 1304 (_UINavigationParallaxTransition.m:383)
5   UIKitCore                       0x182c2acf4 +[UIView(Animation) performWithoutAnimation:] + 104 (UIView.m:14461)
6   UIKitCore                       0x183144bb8 __53-[_UINavigationParallaxTransition animateTransition:]_block_invoke + 260 (_UINavigationParallaxTransition.m:319)
7   UIKitCore                       0x182e91458 +[UIView _performBlockDelayingTriggeringResponderEvents:forScene:] + 252 (UIView.m:15984)
8   UIKitCore                       0x182fb249c -[_UINavigationParallaxTransition animateTransition:] + 1092 (_UINavigationParallaxTransition.m:317)
9   UIKitCore                       0x182f276ec ___UIViewControllerTransitioningRunCustomTransition_block_invoke_2 + 76 (UIViewControllerTransitioning.m:0)
10  UIKitCore                       0x182ecee34 +[UIKeyboardSceneDelegate _pinInputViewsForKeyboardSceneDelegate:onBehalfOfResponder:duringBlock:] + 172 (UIKeyboardSceneDelegate.m:1968)
11  UIKitCore                       0x1834cd880 ___UIViewControllerTransitioningRunCustomTransition_block_invoke.663 + 204 (UIViewControllerTransitioning.m:1258)
12  UIKitCore                       0x182da8914 +[UIView(Animation) _setAlongsideAnimations:toRunByEndOfBlock:] + 204 (UIView.m:14416)
13  UIKitCore                       0x182da879c _UIViewControllerTransitioningRunCustomTransition + 628 (UIViewControllerTransitioning.m:1249)
14  UIKitCore                       0x182e60ed8 -[UINavigationController _startCustomTransition:] + 3412 (UINavigationController.m:2224)
15  UIKitCore                       0x182d2bbec -[UINavigationController _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded:] + 692 (UINavigationController.m:7291)
16  UIKitCore                       0x182d29e28 -[UINavigationController __viewWillLayoutSubviews] + 168 (UINavigationController.m:7596)
17  UIKitCore                       0x182d66bf0 -[UILayoutContainerView layoutSubviews] + 228 (UILayoutContainerView.m:88)
18  UIKitCore                       0x182be1498 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 2768 (UIView.m:18074)
19  QuartzCore                      0x184440f10 CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 536 (CALayer.mm:10004)
20  QuartzCore                      0x18444f664 CA::Layer::layout_and_display_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 144 (CALayer.mm:2476)
21  QuartzCore                      0x184479fa8 CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*, double, double*) + 480 (CAContextInternal.mm:2549)
22  QuartzCore                      0x1844b8910 CA::Transaction::commit() + 680 (CATransactionInternal.mm:449)
23  QuartzCore                      0x184617394 CA::Transaction::flush_as_runloop_observer(bool) + 72 (CATransactionInternal.mm:941)
24  CoreFoundation                  0x1807dbd04 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 36 (CFRunLoop.c:1799)
25  CoreFoundation                  0x18076a334 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 572 (CFRunLoop.c:1912)
26  CoreFoundation                  0x1807c89c0 __CFRunLoopRun + 1052 (CFRunLoop.c:2958)
27  CoreFoundation                  0x1807d631c CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 600 (CFRunLoop.c:3247)
28  GraphicsServices                0x19c174600 GSEventRunModal + 164 (GSEvent.c:2200)
29  UIKitCore                       0x182fae9b0 -[UIApplication _run] + 1084 (UIApplication.m:3409)
30  UIKitCore                       0x182fae424 UIApplicationMain + 2204 (UIApplication.m:4949)
31  SuperApp                        0x1028eec30 main + 68 (AppDelegate.swift:24)
32  dyld                            0x102f2121c start + 520 (dyldMain.cpp:857)

Thread 0 name:
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001b63471f4 __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001f0e0123c pthread_kill + 268 (pthread.c:1609)
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x000000018b8b2500 __abort + 128 (abort.c:155)
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x000000018b8b2480 abort + 176 (abort.c:126)
4   libc++abi.dylib                 0x0000000198ff0a7c abort_message + 132 (abort_message.cpp:78)
5   libc++abi.dylib                 0x0000000198fe19b8 demangling_terminate_handler() + 352 (cxa_default_handlers.cpp:67)
6   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x0000000198eef2fc _objc_terminate() + 144 (objc-exception.mm:701)
7   SuperApp                        0x0000000102ae3b00 CLSTerminateHandler+ 2079488 () + 348
8   libc++abi.dylib                 0x0000000198fefe10 std::__terminate(void (*)()) + 20 (cxa_handlers.cpp:59)
9   libc++abi.dylib                 0x0000000198ff2dc4 __cxa_rethrow + 148 (cxa_exception.cpp:616)
10  libobjc.A.dylib                 0x0000000198eeb1d4 objc_exception_rethrow + 44 (objc-exception.mm:604)
11  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001807d6408 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 836 (CFRunLoop.c:3262)
12  GraphicsServices                0x000000019c174600 GSEventRunModal + 164 (GSEvent.c:2200)
13  UIKitCore                       0x0000000182fae9b0 -[UIApplication _run] + 1084 (UIApplication.m:3409)
14  UIKitCore                       0x0000000182fae424 UIApplicationMain + 2204 (UIApplication.m:4949)
15  SuperApp                        0x00000001028eec30 main + 68 (AppDelegate.swift:24)
16  dyld                            0x0000000102f2121c start + 520 (dyldMain.cpp:857)

Thread 1 name:
Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001b6321b78 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001b6320edc mach_msg + 76 (mach_msg.c:119)
2   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001807c94c8 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 372 (CFRunLoop.c:2641)
3   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001807c8a60 __CFRunLoopRun + 1212 (CFRunLoop.c:2979)
4   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001807d631c CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 600 (CFRunLoop.c:3247)
5   Foundation                      0x0000000181f7b018 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 232 (NSRunLoop.m:377)
6   Foundation                      0x0000000181f7aee4 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runUntilDate:] + 92 (NSRunLoop.m:424)
7   UIKitCore                       0x0000000182c92cec -[UIEventFetcher threadMain] + 524 (UIEventFetcher.m:1054)
8   Foundation                      0x0000000181fe5a04 __NSThread__start__ + 864 (NSThread.m:742)
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001f0e00220 _pthread_start + 148 (pthread.c:890)
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001f0e0962c thread_start + 8

Thread 2 name:
Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001b6321b78 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001b6320edc mach_msg + 76 (mach_msg.c:119)
2   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001807c94c8 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 372 (CFRunLoop.c:2641)
3   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001807c8a60 __CFRunLoopRun + 1212 (CFRunLoop.c:2979)
4   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001807d631c CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 600 (CFRunLoop.c:3247)
5   AudioSession                    0x00000001897e5330 CADeprecated::GenericRunLoopThread::Entry(void*) + 164 (GenericRunLoopThread.h:95)
6   AudioSession                    0x00000001897eae58 CADeprecated::CAPThread::Entry(CADeprecated::CAPThread*) + 92 (CAPThread.cpp:324)
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001f0e00220 _pthread_start + 148 (pthread.c:890)
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001f0e0962c thread_start + 8

Thread 3 name:
Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001b63474ec select$DARWIN_EXTSN + 8
1   WebRTC                          0x0000000103b18d5c 0x103ac0000 + 363868
2   WebRTC                          0x0000000103b1e95c 0x103ac0000 + 387420
3   WebRTC                          0x0000000103b1de94 0x103ac0000 + 384660
4   WebRTC                          0x0000000103b1f2e4 0x103ac0000 + 389860
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001f0e00220 _pthread_start + 148 (pthread.c:890)
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001f0e0962c thread_start + 8

Thread 4 name:
Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001b6346f8c __psynch_cvwait + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001f0e03e28 _pthread_cond_wait + 1240 (pthread_cond.c:636)
2   WebRTC                          0x0000000103b24604 0x103ac0000 + 411140
3   WebRTC                          0x0000000103b244e0 0x103ac0000 + 410848
4   WebRTC                          0x0000000103b11884 0x103ac0000 + 333956
5   WebRTC                          0x0000000103b1e95c 0x103ac0000 + 387420
6   WebRTC                          0x0000000103b1de94 0x103ac0000 + 384660
7   WebRTC                          0x0000000103b1f2e4 0x103ac0000 + 389860
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001f0e00220 _pthread_start + 148 (pthread.c:890)
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001f0e0962c thread_start + 8

Thread 5 name:
Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001b6346f8c __psynch_cvwait + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001f0e03e28 _pthread_cond_wait + 1240 (pthread_cond.c:636)
2   WebRTC                          0x0000000103b24614 0x103ac0000 + 411156
3   WebRTC                          0x0000000103b244e0 0x103ac0000 + 410848
4   WebRTC                          0x0000000103b11884 0x103ac0000 + 333956
5   WebRTC                          0x0000000103b1e95c 0x103ac0000 + 387420
6   WebRTC                          0x0000000103b1de94 0x103ac0000 + 384660
7   WebRTC                          0x0000000103b1f2e4 0x103ac0000 + 389860
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001f0e00220 _pthread_start + 148 (pthread.c:890)
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001f0e0962c thread_start + 8

Thread 6 name:
Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001b6346f8c __psynch_cvwait + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001f0e03e28 _pthread_cond_wait + 1240 (pthread_cond.c:636)
2   WebRTC                          0x0000000103b24604 0x103ac0000 + 411140
3   WebRTC                          0x0000000103b244e0 0x103ac0000 + 410848
4   WebRTC                          0x0000000103bdf4bc 0x103ac0000 + 1176764
5   WebRTC                          0x0000000103bdee4c 0x103ac0000 + 1175116
6   WebRTC                          0x0000000103b23fcc 0x103ac0000 + 409548
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001f0e00220 _pthread_start + 148 (pthread.c:890)
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001f0e0962c thread_start + 8

Thread 7 name:
Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001b6321b78 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001b6320edc mach_msg + 76 (mach_msg.c:119)
2   SuperApp                        0x0000000102ad1320 CLSMachExceptionServer + 100
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001f0e00220 _pthread_start + 148 (pthread.c:890)
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001f0e0962c thread_start + 8

Thread 8 name:
Thread 8:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001b6321b78 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001b6320edc mach_msg + 76 (mach_msg.c:119)
2   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001807c94c8 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 372 (CFRunLoop.c:2641)
3   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001807c8a60 __CFRunLoopRun + 1212 (CFRunLoop.c:2979)
4   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001807d631c CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 600 (CFRunLoop.c:3247)
5   CFNetwork                       0x00000001811bae6c +[__CFN_CoreSchedulingSetRunnable _run:] + 464 (CoreSchedulingSet.mm:1372)
6   Foundation                      0x0000000181fe5a04 __NSThread__start__ + 864 (NSThread.m:742)
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001f0e00220 _pthread_start + 148 (pthread.c:890)
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001f0e0962c thread_start + 8

Thread 9 name:
Thread 9:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001b63474ec select$DARWIN_EXTSN + 8
1   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001808068a8 __CFSocketManager + 648 (CFSocket.c:1343)
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001f0e00220 _pthread_start + 148 (pthread.c:890)
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001f0e0962c thread_start + 8

Thread 10 name:
Thread 10:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001b6321b78 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001b6320edc mach_msg + 76 (mach_msg.c:119)
2   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001807c94c8 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 372 (CFRunLoop.c:2641)
3   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001807c8a60 __CFRunLoopRun + 1212 (CFRunLoop.c:2979)
4   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001807d631c CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 600 (CFRunLoop.c:3247)
5   Foundation                      0x0000000181f7b018 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 232 (NSRunLoop.m:377)
6   CocoaAsyncSocket                0x000000010323e0b4 +[GCDAsyncSocket cfstreamThread:] + 376 (GCDAsyncSocket.m:7655)
7   Foundation                      0x0000000181fe5a04 __NSThread__start__ + 864 (NSThread.m:742)
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001f0e00220 _pthread_start + 148 (pthread.c:890)
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001f0e0962c thread_start + 8

Thread 11:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001f0e09618 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 12:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001f0e09618 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 13:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001f0e09618 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 14 name:
Thread 14:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001b6349068 kevent_id + 8
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018047774c _dispatch_kq_poll + 220 (event_kevent.c:750)
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000180478210 _dispatch_event_loop_wait_for_ownership + 436 (event_kevent.c:2203)
3   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000180463eb0 __DISPATCH_WAIT_FOR_QUEUE__ + 364 (queue.c:1670)
4   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000180463a38 _dispatch_sync_f_slow + 164 (queue.c:1751)
5   CoreData                        0x0000000187b8b77c -[NSManagedObjectContext performBlockAndWait:] + 268 (NSManagedObjectContext.m:4015)
6   ChatCore                        0x00000001043d8d5c specialized NSManagedObjectContext.fetch<A>(where:sortedBy:) + 468 (NSManagedObjectContext+ChatCore.swift:112)
7   ChatCore                        0x0000000104363cd0 CoreDataMessageStorage.fetchSentUnreadMessages(forConversationWith:currentUser:) + 792 (CoreDataMessageStorage.swift:663)
8   ChatCore                        0x00000001043ce87c ChatMessageStore.fetchSentUnreadMessages(forConversationWith:currentUser:) + 32 (ChatMessageStore.swift:158)
9   ChatCore                        0x00000001043ce87c closure #3 in XMPPConversationHistoryModule.xmppMessageArchiveModule(_:didFinishArchiveFor:) + 64 (XMPPConversationHistoryModule.swift:137)
10  ChatCore                        0x00000001043ce87c thunk for @callee_guaranteed (@guaranteed XMPPJID) -> (@owned [Message]?, @error @owned Error) + 64 (<compiler-generated>:0)
11  ChatCore                        0x00000001043ce87c specialized Optional.flatMap<A>(_:) + 64 (<compiler-generated>:0)
12  ChatCore                        0x00000001043ce87c specialized XMPPConversationHistoryModule.xmppMessageArchiveModule(_:didFinishArchiveFor:) + 744 (XMPPConversationHistoryModule.swift:136)
13  ChatCore                        0x0000000104372e80 XMPPConversationHistoryModule.xmppMessageArchiveModule(_:didFinishArchiveFor:) + 12 (<compiler-generated>:124)
14  ChatCore                        0x0000000104372e80 protocol witness for XMPPMessageArchiveModuleDelegate.xmppMessageArchiveModule(_:didFinishArchiveFor:) in conformance XMPPConversationHistoryModule + 12 (XMPPMessageArchiveModule.swift:0)
15  ChatCore                        0x0000000104372e80 specialized XMPPMessageArchiveModule.xmppMessageArchiveManagement(_:didFinishReceivingMessagesWith:for:) + 356
16  ChatCore                        0x0000000104371594 XMPPMessageArchiveModule.xmppMessageArchiveManagement(_:didFinishReceivingMessagesWith:for:) + 16 (<compiler-generated>:0)
17  ChatCore                        0x0000000104371594 @objc XMPPMessageArchiveModule.xmppMessageArchiveManagement(_:didFinishReceivingMessagesWith:for:) + 96
18  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001807c5e04 __invoking___ + 148
19  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018076cc3c -[NSInvocation invoke] + 376 (NSForwarding.m:3448)
20  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018076c690 -[NSInvocation invokeWithTarget:] + 80 (NSForwarding.m:3549)
21  XMPPFramework                   0x0000000104053fac __42-[GCDMulticastDelegate forwardInvocation:]_block_invoke + 40 (GCDMulticastDelegate.m:281)
22  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000180451c6c _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 32 (init.c:1510)
23  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000180453a78 _dispatch_client_callout + 20 (object.m:560)
24  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018045b8bc _dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 692 (inline_internal.h:2603)
25  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018045c4c4 _dispatch_lane_invoke + 412 (queue.c:3926)
26  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001804678f4 _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 780 (queue.c:6720)
27  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001f0e02058 _pthread_wqthread + 288 (pthread.c:2496)
28  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001f0e09620 start_wqthread + 8

Thread 15:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001f0e09618 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 16:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001f0e09618 start_wqthread + 0

EOF
```

Comment: Identical to https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/109601

Answer (score 1):

Its because this crash is possibly a side effect of your view configuration and happens in an Apple framework, noticed you are also using a beta version, try running the same code in ios 14.6, if you can reproduce the crash with the device connected you can enable the Exception breakpoint in Xcode to isolate the line that triggered the chain of events.